# Using JSON Reader in API 8 in android

Tags: android, json, jsonreader

I have a huge json data which i got from a http , i tired the JSON Reader , and passing a string to the JSON object, both ways worked but i prefred the JSON Reader which takse an Input stream , because the string buffer for some point of time won't be able to hold all the json data.
My problem is that JSON reader is avaiable for API 11 , and i'm developing my android application to work on API 8 and higer, is there away to use the JSON reader in API 8?
or is there another JSON parser which may take an input stream to parse the data?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: for large json i'm using jackson library which have [streaming api](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example)

Comment: You may want [`GSON with STREAMING`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming). Gson includes streaming from version 1.6 with the addition of the `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` classes in the GSON Library...

Comment: May be this [LINK](http://tech.xtremelabs.com/parsing-json-data-efficiently-on-android-jsonreader/) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just include the JsonReader source code from the Android project into your app's source - there's only a handful of related classes, and they're fairly simple & self-contained, so it should be too much trouble to add.

[Here's a good place to find the code...](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/util/JsonReader.java?av=f)